# my app is not being displayed in the screen

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I am a beginner python programmer and I have been making this app that tells what time it is ,but when I run it, nothing happens. the program is running, but it's not being displayed in the screen.Here is my code for the app.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400+200-200')
root.title('clock')
lable = tk.Label(root , font=('unispace' , 30 , 'bold' ) , text = 'temporary' , bg = 'blue' , fg = 'white')
lable.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = 'nsew')
l = 1
while l != 0:
    seconds = time.time()
    current_time = time.ctime(seconds)
    lable.config(text = current_time)
    lable.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = 'nsew')
    time.sleep(1)
root.mainloop()
```

can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter`, like all GUI libraries, is event drive.  When you create a graphical element, nothing actually happens.  All that does is send messages.  The messages don't get popped and processed until the `root.mainloop`.  You need to think about these problems in an event driven way.  You cannot use `time.sleep` nor can you make infinite loops.

You need to use `root.after` to request a callback after a second.  That can update the UI and request another callback a second later.

```
def update():
    seconds = time.time()
    current_time = time.ctime(seconds)
    lable.config(text = current_time)
    lable.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = 'nsew')
    root.after( 1000, update )
update()
root.mainloop()
```